# format irregular json data in method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a service that returns a json with irregular data (see example below), but more complex, where there are pages or documents

```
dataFromService: [
    {
        event_data: '2021-03-18T15:20:31.314Z', // if  !null = page
        event_category: 'news',
        event_title_en: 'page title',
    },
    {
        event_list_news_events_event_data: 'not null', // if  !null = doc
        event_list_news_events: [
            { event_category: 'news' },
            { event_title: 'page title' }
        ],
        publication_date: '2021-02-12T15:20:31.314Z'
    }
    ...
]
```

my idea is to format the data via a method like below

```
newData: [
    {   
        itemType: 'page',
        itemCategory: 'news',
        itemTitle: 'page title',
        itemDate: '2021-03-18T15:20:31.314Z',                       
    },
    {   
        itemType: 'doc',
        itemCategory: 'event',
        itemTitle: 'doc title',
        itemDate: '2021-02-12T15:20:31.314Z',                       
    },
    ...
]
```

I thought of a solution like this

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            myList: []
        }
    }
  }),
created () {
    this.dataSource();
},
methods: {
    dataSource: function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.dataFromService.length; i++) {
            let elem = {};

            if (this.dataFromService[i].event_data && this.dataFromService[i].event_data != null) {
                elem['itemType'] = 'page';
                elem['itemCategory'] = this.dataFromService[i].event_category;
                elem['itemDate'] = this.dataFromService[i].event_data;
                if (this.lang === 'en') {
                    elem['itemTitle'] = this.dataFromService[i].event_title_en;
                }
            } else if (this.dataFromService[i].event_list_news_events_event_data && this.dataFromService[i].event_list_news_events_event_data != null) {
                elem['itemType'] = 'doc';
                elem['itemCategory'] = this.dataFromService[i].event_list_news_events.event_category;
                elem['itemDate'] = this.dataFromService[i].publication_date;
                elem['itemTitle'] = this.dataFromService[i].event_list_news_events.event_title;
            }

            this.myList.push(elem);
        }
        console.log('myList: ', JSON.stringify(this.myList));
    }
}
```

is there a better way than the for loop?
What is the best way to call the method? in created, beforeMount, mounted hooks?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the following two conditions are equivalent. The first checks if `event_data` is truthy, which includes non-`null` values, so the second condition is redundant:

```js
if (
  this.dataFromService[i].event_data &&
  this.dataFromService[i].event_data != null // covered by 1st condition
) {...}
```

The same is true for:

```js
if (
  this.dataFromService[i].event_list_news_events_event_data &&
  this.dataFromService[i].event_list_news_events_event_data != null // covered by 1st condition
) {...}
```

So the second conditions noted above can be removed from your code.

I think the code you have is already fine, but another way to write your loop is to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `dataFromService[]` to create a new array based on the original. You could move the item formatting into utility functions (`toPageItem` and `toDocsItem`) to be called when the item is a page or doc. Otherwise, return `null`. Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the result to remove the `null` items.

```html
<script>
  const toPageItem = item => ({
    itemType: 'page',
    itemCategory: item.event_category,
    itemDate: item.event_data,
    itemTitle: item.event_title_en || item.event_title,
  })
  const toDocsItem = item => ({
    itemType: 'docs',
    itemCategory: item.event_category,
    itemDate: item.publication_date,
    itemTitle: item.event_list_news_events.event_title,
  })

  export default {
    mounted() {
      this.dataSource()
    },
    methods: {
      dataSource() {
        this.myList = this.dataFromService.map(item => {
          if (item.event_data) {
            return toPageItem(item)
          } else if (item.event_list_news_events_event_data) {
            return toDocsItem(item)
          } else {
            return null
          }
        }).filter(Boolean)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The `dataSource()` method should probably be called from the `mounted()` hook so that it's only run when your data is ready to be displayed.

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ExWLQwW)